# Is closed w/o comment auto flag still necessary?

Tags: discussion, flags, closed-questions, community-user

Most of the time now when questions are closed (put on hold), there is a reason given in the on-hold notice. Still though many of these get auto flagged because "closed w/o comment". Is that still necessary?

[Here is an example](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11348/can-you-help-me-decrypt-this#question) of one that I just closed that got auto-flagged as not having a comment.

**Update**
Just as an update. We don't get a lot of questions that end up being auto-flagged as not having a comment, but the last few we have gotten have all been not helpful.

Comment: @Dukeling On [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/determining-encryption-algorithm-given-key-and-cipher-size) we got an auto-flag of "closed w/o comment". Yet when I look at the reason stated in the "on hold" box, it seems like a pretty good explanation so I don't think a comment is necessary. There were others like this I just cleared too which is why I asked.

Comment: I thought those happened only on binding close votes. In any case, I feel that they are fine in the case of community decisions, but unnecessary when a mod closes a question. If the community trusts an individual enough to let him cast binding votes, it stands to reason that the user would be responsible enough to comment as well, if its needed.

Comment: @Dukeling I cleared the flag. It was the auto-flag that I'm talking about.

Comment: Oh, auto-flags, not [tag:auto-comments]. The tag threw me.

Comment: @mikeazo Keep in mind that the flag doesn't mean that *all* of such posts need a comment, merely that some do.  If that particular post is clear enough just clear the flag.  The question is, are almost all of such flags that you come across being cleared, or are they being acted on with beneficial comments?  Perhaps some stats on percentage cleared in the past 30 days would help answer that.

Comment: @Servy, agreed that would be interesting.

Comment: @Dukeling yes, my apologies. I removed the tag.

Comment: Here's [another example](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12456/select-right-ssl-cipher-suite-for-set-top-boxes-sh4?noredirect=1). I'm not sure why those flags are even generated for migrations at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In particular, the flags are useless if the question was closed by

- one of the new custom close reasons -- their description are (or ought to be) explanation enough or
- with a case-specific close reason that is automatically added as a comment.

I propose that in these cases, Community should not flag.